# awk + gsub special characters

Tags: awk, gsub

G       .       .       PASS    VRT=1   GT      0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0
    G       .       .       PASS    VRT=1   GT      0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0
    C       .       .       PASS    VRT=1   GT      0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0     0/0

I have a file as shown above and i am trying to replace 0/0 with text in column 1.

```
awk -F'\t' '{ gsub("0/0", $1/$1);}1' OFS="\t" file.txt
```

The output should look like:

```
G       .       .       PASS    VRT=1   GT      G/G     G/G     G/G     G/G     G/G     G/G     
G       .       .       PASS    VRT=1   GT      G/G     G/G     G/G     G/G     G/G     G/G     
C       .       .       PASS    VRT=1   GT      C/C     C/C     C/C     C/C     C/C     C/C
```

And it throws the error "awk: division by zero". Looks like i am not matching the special characters. Could someone help.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean :

```
awk -F'\t' 'gsub("0/0", $1"/"$1)+1' OFS="\t" file.txt
```